# Mongoose create multiple index and personalize quety to call with specific index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to do many indexes over my model and when i am doing query use a specific index in that query

this is my model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ThingSchema = new Schema({

        word:{
            type: 'ObjectId',
            required:true
        },
        frecuency:{
            type: String,
            default:'enabled'
        },
        document:{
            documentId:{
                type: 'ObjectId'
            },
            quality:{
                type: Number
            }
        },
        location: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2d' 
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema);
```

I would like to have these indexes:

- index by word (is a string)
- index by location (is geoindex)
- index by word and location

Now when I am doing a query I would like to specify which index to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your `module.exports` line:

```
ThingSchema.index({word: 1});
// all other indexes you want to add...
```

And when it's time to make a query, use `hint()` to specify which index to use:

```
Thing.find({...}).hint({word: 1});
```